# How do I make a list of objects that descend from traits in Scala?

Tags: scala

```
trait Foo
class A extends Foo
class B extends Foo
List[Foo](new A(), new B())

error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.B
 required: this.Foo
       List[Foo](new A(), new B())
                          ^
```

What's the correct way to have a list of `Foo`'s?

EDIT: updated to clarify multiple descendant classes

Comment: This code should compile fine. Your problem must be at a different place...

Comment: You're right - it seems like the issue is with the Spark shell that I'm using

Answer (score 1):

This actually appears to work, the issue must be with the Spark shell I was using.

EDIT: Here's the update from the [Spark](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/spark-users/BfpiH7tGDHI) guys.